# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.paypal.core.BaseService.<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, paypal

I have download PayPal Invoice SDK, but when i am trying to run this code, it's giving me exception :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet CreateInvoiceSerlvet threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.paypal.core.BaseService.<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V
    at com.paypal.svcs.services.InvoiceService.<init>(InvoiceService.java:103)
    at com.sample.invoice.CreateInvoiceSerlvet.doPost(CreateInvoiceSerlvet.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Any idea, Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a missing jar, check your dependencies are in your classpath

Comment: No i have already included all the required jar files in my WEB-INF/lib forlder. com.paypal.core.BaseService is also there.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and build before run. That may solve the issue since you already add required jars.make sure that those jar visible to the project, and other words add those jar to class path.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but I had this same problem and there are no much references for this particular exception (actually I think is always this same question with the same answers). I was working with a sample code for MassPay (https://github.com/paypal/codesamples-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sample/merchant/MassPay.java) and got:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.paypal.core.BaseService.<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V
    at urn.ebay.api.PayPalAPI.PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.<init>(PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.java:190)
    at urn.ebay.api.PayPalAPI.PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.<init>(PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.java:175)
    at urn.ebay.api.PayPalAPI.PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.<init>(PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.java:160)
```

In my case, I've solved the problem by modifying the merchantsdk's version, the latest version now is the **2.13.117** but I had changed it to **2.2.98**.
 Hope it helps someone else.